# What would cause $string1 = $string2 to return false when their values are the same?

Tags: xml, xslt

Yes, I may very well be dealing with a buggy processor or application that invokes the processor, but here is the problem I am having anyway.

In my application/processor I am able to do this (assume queryString1=Yes):

`<xsl:variable name="qs1" select="'%queryString1%'" />`

Then, to illustrate the problem, let's do this:

`<xsl:variable name="check" select="'Yes'" />`

To verify the data, the following return values as expected "Yes":

`<xsl:value-of select="$qs1" />` = Yes

`<xsl:value-of select="$check" />` = Yes

The problem is that I would expect the following statements to return $true but they return $false.

`<xsl:value-of select="$qs1 = $check" />` = $false

`<xsl:value-of select="contains($qs1,$check)" />` = $false

`<xsl:value-of select="compare($qs1,$check)" />` = -1

I've even tried crazy stuff like

`<xsl:variable name="test" select="concat($qs1,$check)" />`
`<xsl:value-of select="$test" />` = YesYes
but

`<xsl:value-of select="compare($test,'YesYes')" />` returns -1

The question then becomes, what could possibly be going on inside the machine to cause this and how to get around it?

Comment: In which language (XPath, XSLT?) do you expect `'%queryString1%'` to be anything but a string literal containing the characters `%queryString1%`?

Comment: It is a mystery to me how it is accomplished but the application that invokes the XSLT (Saxon) processor allows me to do that in order to pass query strings from the URL to the  stylesheet.
While those details may be relevant to understanding the why of the behavior, the fact remains that doing value-of select="$qs1"  outputs the expected value of Yes.
Further, if I try something like `<xsl:value-of select='$qs1/@*" />` returns an error  (as expected) that tells me that $qs1 is of type xs:string which is also the type of $check. So what causes the comparisons to return $false?

Comment: Post a minimal but complete stylesheet that gives the claimed result when you run Saxon from the command line so that it can be reproduced or explain which tool you use to run the XSLT and better add a tag for it so that any users can chime in and reproduce and perhaps explain it.

Comment: Wild guess: encoding-issue? UTF 16 with something singular encoding?

Comment: Enconding sounds like a good clue.  How do I convert the encoding of a string?  How do I check the current encoding of a string?